# Grab an element's value within each of the dynamic div

Tags: jquery, object, recursion, dynamic, html-select

I've an array ob object using which I'm creating dynamic divs. Each of my object has a property 'logoColor' which has a value either 1 or 2.

Now in each of my dynamic div I've a dropdown 'Logo Colour' which has a value of 1 or 2. But, it is displayed as 'Red' or 'Blue'.

The user has on option to change any of the logoColor value in the dropdown.

How do I grab the value of each of the dropdown from the dynamically generated divs in the same function sendData() which I'm calling on click of the 'Send Data' button?

Code Snippet:

```js
var myData =[{
  "company" : "ABC",
  "logoColor": "1"
},{
  "company" : "BCD",
  "logoColor": "2"
},{
  "company" : "CDE", 
  "logoColor": "1"
},{
  "company" : "DEF", 
  "logoColor": "2"
}];

  
function createDisplay() {
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
 $('.container').append(
   $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
  $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
  $('<span>').text(obj.company),
  $('<br /><label>').text('Logo Colour: '),
  $('<select>').addClass('selectLogo').append(
    $('<option>').val('1').text('Red').prop('selected', true),
    $('<option>').val('2').text('Blue')
  ).val(obj.logoColor)
   )
 )
  });
}

function sendData(){
 
  myData.forEach(function(obj){
 var logoColor = $('.selectLogo').val();
  });
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myData);
  var dataContent = {'content': myJSON};
  
  $.ajax({
 url:"/abc/myNewData",
 type: "POST",
 data: dataContent,
 dataType: 'JSON',
 success: function(response){
   alert("Data sent successfully!");
 }
  }); 
}
```

```css
.box {
 background-color: skyblue;
 height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid lightgrey;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createDisplay()">Create Data </button> 
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendData()">Send Data </button> 
<div class="container">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
var logoColor = [];
$('.box .selectLogo option:selected').each(function() {
  logoColor.push($(this).val())
})
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(logoColor);
var dataContent = {
  'content': myJSON
};
```

This will loop through all your divs select and return the selected value.

```js
var myData = [{
  "company": "ABC",
  "logoColor": "1"
}, {
  "company": "BCD",
  "logoColor": "2"
}, {
  "company": "CDE",
  "logoColor": "1"
}, {
  "company": "DEF",
  "logoColor": "2"
}];


function createDisplay() {
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
    $('.container').append(
      $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
        $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
        $('<span>').text(obj.company),
        $('<br /><label>').text('Logo Colour: '),
        $('<select>').addClass('selectLogo').append(
          $('<option>').val('1').text('Red').prop('selected', true),
          $('<option>').val('2').text('Blue')
        ).val(obj.logoColor)
      )
    )
  });
}

function sendData() {
  var logoColor = [];
  $('.box .selectLogo option:selected').each(function() {
    logoColor.push($(this).val())
  })

  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(logoColor);
  var dataContent = {
    'content': myJSON
  };

  console.log(dataContent)
  $.ajax({
    url: "/abc/myNewData",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataContent,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Data sent successfully!");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createDisplay()">Create Data </button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendData()">Send Data </button>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to loop through dynamically generated div as follows:

```
var myData = [];
    $("div.box").each(function(i){
  var obj = {};
   console.log("index"+i);
    obj["company"] = $(this).find("span").text();
    obj["logoColor"] =  $(this).find('.selectLogo').val();
    myData.push(obj);
  });
```

```js
var myData = [{
  "company": "ABC",
  "logoColor": "1"
}, {
  "company": "BCD",
  "logoColor": "2"
}, {
  "company": "CDE",
  "logoColor": "1"
}, {
  "company": "DEF",
  "logoColor": "2"
}];


function createDisplay() {
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
    $('.container').append(
      $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
        $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
        $('<span>').text(obj.company),
        $('<br /><label>').text('Logo Colour: '),
        $('<select>').addClass('selectLogo').append(
          $('<option>').val('1').text('Red').prop('selected', true),
          $('<option>').val('2').text('Blue')
        ).val(obj.logoColor)
      )
    )
  });
}

function sendData() {
  var myData = [];
  $("div.box").each(function(i) {
    var obj = {};
    console.log("index"+i);
    obj["company"] = $(this).find("span").text();
    obj["logoColor"] = $(this).find('.selectLogo').val();
    myData.push(obj);
  });
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myData);
  alert(myJSON);
  var dataContent = {
    'content': myJSON
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "/abc/myNewData",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataContent,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Data sent successfully!");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createDisplay()">Create Data </button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendData()">Send Data </button>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: `find("span").val()` should be `find("span").text()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: Thanks :)

Comment: Any idea on how I get index of each div with class '.box ' at the same time? I tried $(this).parents('.box').index(); But it always returns -1!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try : 

var logoColor = $(this).find(".selectLogo").val();
```

Comment: $(this) will return the 'Send Data' button as I'd clicked on that and my function sendData() is called on the click of it.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.